# find a specific value in json file and append suffix to it using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I want to match a specific value in json file and append an suffix to it in the same json file.

Here is my json file

```
{
  "apiVersion": "argoproj.io/v1alpha1",
  "kind": "Workflow",
  "metadata": {
    "generateName": "kns-vm-"
  },
  "spec": {
    "templates": [{
      "inputs": {
        "parameters": [{
          "name": "un",
          "value": "org"
        }]
      },
      "dag": {
        "tasks": [{
            "name": "create-ns",
            "templateRef": {
              "name": "wft-kn"
            },
            "arguments": {
              "parameters": [{
                "name": "un",
                "value": "{{inputs.parameters.un}}"
              }]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "create-sm",
            "templateRef": {
              "name": "wft-sn"
            },
            "arguments": {
              "parameters": [{
                "name": "un",
                "value": "{{inputs.parameters.un}}"
              }]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

in this I want to find value `wft-sn` and append an suffix `-test` to it

so the updated json file should look like this

```
{
  "apiVersion": "argoproj.io/v1alpha1",
  "kind": "Workflow",
  "metadata": {
    "generateName": "kns-vm-"
  },
  "spec": {
    "templates": [{
      "inputs": {
        "parameters": [{
          "name": "un",
          "value": "org"
        }]
      },
      "dag": {
        "tasks": [{
            "name": "create-ns",
            "templateRef": {
              "name": "wft-kn"
            },
            "arguments": {
              "parameters": [{
                "name": "un",
                "value": "{{inputs.parameters.un}}"
              }]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "create-sm",
            "templateRef": {
              "name": "wft-sn-test"
            },
            "arguments": {
              "parameters": [{
                "name": "un",
                "value": "{{inputs.parameters.un}}"
              }]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

I am using the `jq` command like below but it is not working

`jq '. | select(.spec.templates[].dag.tasks[].templateRef.name == "wft-sn").name |= . + "-test"' demo.json`

what mistake I am doing here? how we can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` reproduces its input if the condition evaluates to `true`. Apply it therefore only to the part you want to test. Also, keep the overall context in parentheses to retain it on top-level for output:

```sh
jq '(.spec.templates[].dag.tasks[].templateRef.name | select(. == "wft-sn")) += "-test"'
```

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "argoproj.io/v1alpha1",
  "kind": "Workflow",
  "metadata": {
    "generateName": "kns-vm-"
  },
  "spec": {
    "templates": [
      {
        "inputs": {
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "un",
              "value": "org"
            }
          ]
        },
        "dag": {
          "tasks": [
            {
              "name": "create-ns",
              "templateRef": {
                "name": "wft-kn"
              },
              "arguments": {
                "parameters": [
                  {
                    "name": "un",
                    "value": "{{inputs.parameters.un}}"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "create-sm",
              "templateRef": {
                "name": "wft-sn-test"
              },
              "arguments": {
                "parameters": [
                  {
                    "name": "un",
                    "value": "{{inputs.parameters.un}}"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have also removed the unnecessary `. |` and reduced `|= . +` to `+=`.